# decoding/accessing the video stream of ip camera model WD6B

Tags: udp, video-streaming, vlc, codec, ip-camera

I have an ip camera that I'm trying to get a video stream from for use in Agent DVR.  I have successfully added a number of other types of cameras but this one is proving difficult as I can't seem to get Agent DVR to see it using any combination of settings or camera stream urls.  It's a camera like this one:

https://www.sunsky-online.com/view/1434395/WD6A%204K%20WiFi%20Wireless%20Remote%20Home%20Network%20HD%20Camera%20%20Support%20Motion%20Detection%20%20%20Infrared%20Night%20Vision%20%20%20TF%20Card.htm

The camera uses the HDWifiCamPro android app for viewing the video. I used nmap to find out which local ip address (192.168.0.67) the camera was on and I've monitored the apps network traffic to see what's being sent and the video stream seems to be sent on a UDP stream but the port changes each time the app connects to the camera.  I've tried using VLC to connect to the stream but I've had no success.  The urls I've used are as follows when opening a network stream in vlc:

```
rtsp://192.168.0.67:{port}
rtp://192.168.0.67:{port}
mms://192.168.0.67:{port}
udp://192.168.0.67:{port}
udp://@:{port}
udp://0.0.0.@:{port}
```

The mac address indicates the chinese manufacturer is:  SHENZHEN BILIAN ELECTRONIC CO.，LTD

The udp packets from the network sniffer (PCAppDroid) look as follows:

```
2c 5a dd 6f 14 27 88 67  62 2d a1 f0 f0 f1 05 58  ,Z.o.'.gb-.....X
53 84 4d 06 f8 37 14 26  9b fe 51 32 1e 67 37 14  S.M..7.&..Q2.g7.
26 7d 33 20 73 69 7c cf  32 1e 67 36 89 ff c0 35  &}3 si|.2.g6...5
72 9a 1d 62 51 09 2c ad  be 5b 44 15 ce 4c 83 58  r..bQ.,..[D..L.X
c2 63 9a 7a fa 7a c4 a4  f3 a6 05 b2 81 40 62 22  .c.z.z.......@b"
e1 35 24 1d c7 7b db 89  46 69 32 af ea 8a f6 f1  .5$..{..Fi2.....
62 b2 24 68 bd 80 47 30  ae dd bb 55 ab 83 ad eb  b.$h..G0...U....
9e 7e 16 64 6e 08 47 bd  a1 76 aa 84 52 eb c2 99  .~.dn.G..v..R...
dc 82 d8 d0 4e a7 44 3d  ec 74 1d 41 a1 9a ba f7  ....N.D=.t.A....
f2 d2 70 c3 b1 59 c6 fa  b1 78 3b 4c cc 0e 26 70  ..p..Y...x;L..&p
46 19 da d2 2f d9 84 a0  22 b1 ff c0 5c 32 3c a6  F.../..."...\2<.
62 03 cd 2c 10 35 fd de  e6 d5 c8 13 79 42 94 c3  b..,.5......yB..
6e 9b 3b 1d 76 bd 05 33  3e c4 bb 12 8d 86 cf ac  n.;.v..3>.......
cb b9 0f 7f 17 e0 ee 57  42 ff 79 82 60 c4 bd 08  .......WB.y.`...
de 67 eb b2 3a 2f 72 30  a1 73 48 1f 98 43 ab 7f  .g..:/r0.sH..C..
49 56 b8 c7 cb 9c 7b 02  87 85 4e c3 ba be 88 67  IV....{...N....g
42 b7 cc 23 55 2e 29 2d  fd 7c 4e d9 1a 6a 5b a4  B..#U.)-.|N..j[.
c6 b6 8f 83 83 0c 24 08  08 72 f4 71 e1 1b cf 37  ......$..r.q...7
7c 48 bf 27 e2 5a 3e 35  96 c8 d1 ce c3 19 57 7c  |H.'.Z>5......W|
b8 9e c9 17 64 1f 67 e9  30 fc 8e 55 57 de d3 a4  ....d.g.0..UW...
e7 51 1c 3b 44 63 b0 ab  9c f4 aa ff a2 37 a2 33  .Q.;Dc.......7.3
22 2b 2f 20 60 8e e0 3a  1d 40 41 c2 7e ce 6d 3a  "+/ `..:.@A.~.m:
21 38 59 f0 29 b7 13 bf  64 82 7c 2d ef ec 03 6d  !8Y.)...d.|-...m
c3 d7 e3 56 a4 c6 56 4a  5b 84 f6 d8 0e 79 dc 3c  ...V..VJ[....y.<
2b fc 36 13 0b 0b 6d 2d  33 b9 53 53 4e 66 77 d2  +.6...m-3.SSNfw.
12 4b 89 30 f8 92 55 69  b7 ad 6d a1 00 ce 32 62  .K.0..Ui..m...2b
09 c6 79 c1 44 d4 b2 38  cb 5b 10 12 61 eb dc f7  ..y.D..8.[..a...
ae 49 05 c0 c0 12 e5 58  d1 7f 04 a3 75 68 47 56  .I.....X....uhGV
82 3a 15 7f fd 02 5d b0  f5 9e bd 41 5c c4 de 8f  .:....]....A\...
43 89 86 5c b9 16 65 3f  cc fb af 76 96 d1 25 dc  C..\..e?...v..%.
e4 5a bf 7f 42 ab b0 99  29 1c 34 62 ec ce 8a d8  .Z..B...).4b....
37 08 12 f4 a5 9c c7 bc  73 55 f4 31 76 65 ba 3b  7.......sU.1ve.;
48 4f 00 17 35 c7 b6 bb  0a b8 c5 2a 51 d5 a4 b5  HO..5......*Q...
fc 45 ed 57 31 7a 4b 96  f3 ab 82 c0 78 2a 3d 6d  .E.W1zK.....x*=m
80 61 0d 77 42 cf df 8e  75 af 76 e7 9a a3 a3 76  .a.wB...u.v....v
16 6c 6e b4 26 72 b0 38  97 b1 39 cd 1b a5 a3 88  .ln.&r.8..9.....
76 2e e9 c7 12 3d 2f ec  3b e6 a3 6a 27 71 f3 22  v....=/.;..j'q."
28 2a 3d fb ab f9 3b 7d  0a 02 5a 8a 2c 5d 3a cf  (*=...;}..Z.,]:.
62 8d ac a9 c7 a7 0a b2  2f eb 0e 5e ee 9a 9a 0b  b......./..^....
2a 1a 78 d0 f3 bf a1 c6  dc de 60 dd d1 ee d7 37  *.x.......`....7
da 22 4f 43 da 1f 44 27  3a 6e 19 09 f4 2c 14 d9  ."OC..D':n...,..
91 85 f2 f1 94 68 ac d4  73 b9 e9 f5 33 cd 49 f2  .....h..s...3.I.
f6 6f 71 ed 9a 26 d0 6e  a8 13 f7 a8 9e 6b 9a 5c  .oq..&.n.....k.\
8a 22 12 14 ae a7 d3 9e  5b bd 7e 94 fe e2 74 ec  ."......[.~...t.
5d 00 cf 8d 7b 14 78 c1  57 c4 6e 64 c5 64 f1 ef  ]...{.x.W.nd.d..
97 b9 4d 08 a6 61 79 01  01 2c ca 13 fb 50 11 c8  ..M..ay..,...P..
3c 73 9a fa a1 4b ae 3d  82 a7 ce 22 64 0e db 19  <s...K.=..."d...
39 39 df 78 d1 da f9 ee  82 b4 c2 c5 0f f8 5d c6  99.x..........].
13 13 85 10 87 7c 2e 62  c4 32 a3 23 31 60 55 76  .....|.b.2.#1`Uv
8c 9e 00 17 f5 6e 07 9f  bf 9d d5 9a 3f b3 10 e7  .....n......?...
54 af 76 72 3d 58 68 54  03 79 39 af 79 e2 8d be  T.vr=XhT.y9.y...
ff 3e c7 95 87 61 57 9c  7f 2a c5 03 a5 1d 4f cd  .>...aW..*....O.
eb 84 48 d8 27 b1 62 a2  5a 7a cf 85 e1 54 61 3e  ..H.'.b.Zz...Ta>
55 37 1a 66 78 cc 76 61  7c 46 23 e4 9f 40 16 53  U7.fx.va|F#..@.S
7e 96 49 24 c2 14 18 f7  f9 78 70 fc a9 a3 7c 0e  ~.I$.....xp...|.
41 cd e9 c2 2b 4d 74 22  b2 b1 95 b8 d4 12 af 47  A...+Mt".......G
d0 d8 72 3e 93 bf 52 eb  2c 74 b7 81 72 fe 03 b9  ..r>..R.,t..r...
c3 4c e1 7c 64 c5 6a 53  b8 a4 c6 59 bc a7 2e 17  .L.|d.jS...Y....
ee 00 1b 67 46 40 c8 56  af 16 10 65 76 6a 9e a0  ...gF@.V...evj..
a5 80 09 71 3c a7 1b 09  50 4b bd 5c c4 ea 5b 62  ...q<...PK.\..[b
14 d7 8d 70 c9 46 40 0c  10 ac 72 6a 9d b7 29 53  ...p.F@...rj..)S
f9 78 c0 06 c2 39 33 ff  3a ab 8a aa 09 2c d7 34  .x...93.:....,.4
4f c1 9a ac 1b 69 1b d5  2b 13 e2 59 fa 6b 0a eb  O....i..+..Y.k..
b5 e0 0e 17 b0 36 88 64  da 02 bc 99 2c 93 b5 39  .....6.d....,..9
e7 22 ff 26 df 14 70 57
```

The 4th character seems to change reverse alphabetically each time indicating a sequence (from 'o' to 'n' to 'm' etc) but other than that I'm stuck.  I've already ordered a different type of camera that I can use with Agent DVR  but I'd like to crack this puzzle if possible!  I wonder if there's a way to identify the format/codec of the stream?

Answer (score 0):

if it uses the same things for netwave ip cameras i can help you
i have one of netwave ip camera and i can take the stream of it with that code:

```
    import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://ipaddress:port/way/to/video')# if it has a username and password to watch it you can use 'http://username:password@ipaddress:port/way/to/video'

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

if you want to move the camera you can use this [github](https://github.com/TheLogicMaster/Netwave-Camera) page maybe
thats all i know reply to me if you had any errors or questions